# Исключение при загрузке FXML файлов

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Изучаю JavaFX, столкнулся с такой проблемой, не могу прогрузить FXML файлы, выдает `Exception in Application start method`, жалуясь на строку, где происходит загрузка файла `rootLayout = loader.load();` все происходит в одном классе, ниже код. Комментарии какие-никакие указаны, помогите разобраться в чем ошибка, и выдает исключение, вроде логически все правильно, добавлю то, что контроллер к `PersonOverview.fxml` указан правильно, ко второму файлу контроллер не подключал еще, но как понимаю это не должно быть связанно, и путь к самим FXML файлам указан правильно

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;      //создаем переменную типа Stage
    private BorderPane rootLayout;   //создаем переменную типа BorderPane

     /**
     * Данные, в виде наблюдаемого списка адресатов.
     */
    private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Конструктор
     */
    public Main() {
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает данные в виде наблюдаемого списка адресатов.
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData() {
        return personData;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

        initRootLayout();

        showPersonOverview();
    }

    /**
     * Инициализирует корневой макет.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Загружаем корневой макет из fxml файла.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = loader.load();

            // Отображаем сцену, содержащую корневой макет.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Показывает в корневом макете сведения об адресатах.
     */
    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            // Загружаем сведения об адресатах.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = loader.load();

            // Помещаем сведения об адресатах в центр корневого макета.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);

            // Даём контроллеру доступ к главному приложению.
            PersonOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMain(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает главную сцену.
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Полный текст ошибки

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
    at address.Main.initRootLayout(Main.java:69)
    at address.Main.start(Main.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application address.Main
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ошибке `javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane` в `RootLayout.fxml` корневой элемент имеет тип `AnchorPane`, а присвоить его вы пытаетесь полю `rootLayout` имеющему тип `BorderPane`.

Comment: да, я обратил уже на это внимание, но тогда не могу отработать `rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);` вроде это и логично, Центр есть только у Border, но как правильнее добавить тогда на Anchor? или FXML изменять лучше?